# JavaFX TextField OnKeyTyped Not Working Properly

Tags: java, javafx, properties, listener, textfield

**Given**

JavaFX App, Input `TextField` and Submit `Button`

There's an `EventHandler` attached to the `TextField` so that if no text is typed, the `Button` should be disabled and vice versa.

Here's my code:

```
button.setDisable(true); // initially disabled
textField.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if (textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) { // if blank textfield
                 button.setDisable(true);
            } else {
                 button.setDisable(false); 
             }
        }
});
```

Both Controls are initialized properly. And as far as I know, the difference between KeyTyped and KeyPressed/Released is that Typed is for characters that can actually be typed and shown; whereas Pressed/Released is for any keyboard key including Ctrl, Alt...

**Problem**

I type into the `textField` one character, the `button` is still disabled! If I type 2 characters and more and it becomes enabled!

However, when if I do the following:

```
button.setDisable(true);
textField.setOnKeyReleased(
    /*
     exact same code as above
    */
);
```

my problem will be solved.

**Question**

WHY? Where's the flaw in my code? Why doesn't KeyTyped work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: in the time when you handle the `KeyEvent`, it is not sure that the [`textProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--) of your `TextField` was updated or not.

Cleaner and safer approach to add a listener for the `textProperty` of the `TextField` to be notified when the text of the `TextField` changes. Imagine also the usecase that the user pasted some content: in this case there is no `KeyEvent` at all, therefore your `Button` remains disabled.

*Using a listener on textProperty()*

```
button.setDisable(true);
textField.textProperty().addListener((obj, oldVal, newVal) -> {

    if (newVal.trim().isEmpty()) { // if blank textfield
         button.setDisable(true);
    } else {
         button.setDisable(false); 
     }
});
```

... or even shorter ...

```
button.setDisable(true);
textField.textProperty().addListener((obj, oldVal, newVal) -> button.setDisable(newVal.trim().isEmpty()));
```

But, the much cleaner solution to use binding between the [`disableProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty--) of the `Button` and the [`textProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--) of the `TextField`.

*Using a binding between `disableProperty` and `textProperty`*

```
BooleanBinding textIsEmpty = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> textField.getText().trim().isEmpty(), textField.textProperty());
button.disableProperty().bind(textIsEmpty);
```

Comment: In your first aproach, if you use a `ChangeListener` like `(obj, oldVal, newVal) -> { ...}` you even get the new value delivered automatically, without needing to refer back to the `textField`. Anyway, +1 ...

Comment: alright. thanks even though I still don't understand why at one character it doesn't work but with more characters it does!

Comment: @rz3r0 Simple: the text has not been updated yet in the `TextField`at the moment when `setOnKeyTyped()` is called. Hence you are still reading the old (empty) value. The control then updates its text and later calls `setOnKeyReleased()` - there, the new value is available.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lambda parameters @AndreasFester, I have updated the answer, and also I just noticed that the binding does not handle the `trim`, so that part is also updated.